# Python REGEX get weight value from string

Tags: python, regex

I have these strings

```
Gold Standard Whey 10.20 KG Optimum
Gold Standard Whey kg10,20 Optimum
Gold Standard Whey kg.  10.20 Optimum 
Gold Standard Whey 10.20kg. Optimum
```

I need to extract 10.20 or 10,20 using python using regex

I already tested with this regex

```
((kg\.|KG\.|Kg\.|kg|KG|Kg){1}[ ]{0,}\d{1,}?(\.|\,)\d{0,})|(\d{0,}?(\.|\,)\d{1,}[ ]{0,}(kg\.|KG\.|Kg\.|kg|KG|Kg))
```

But looking for a better regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the numbers and the strings only contain numbers you want, why not just something like

```
\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?
```

`(?:...)` is a non capturing group, making it optional with `?` allows to capture non decimal digits as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this simplified regex:

```
((?:[kK][gG]\.?)[ ]*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?[ ]*(?:[kK][gG]\.?))
```